# No usb devices will connect on boot

Tags: windows, boot, desktop

I have a new pc. I added a 2tb hard drive, to expand my storage from my 512gb nvme. My nvme has windows 10 and boots seemingly fine, goes right to windows login screen. The problem is that no usb ports work with any of the mice or keyboards that I plug in. Despite those devices working on my other computers.

I see no lights flashing on the motherboard on boot. The pc is also not just in a display state, as the time and date are functioning as normal. I ended up unplugging everything from the motherboard and the usbs still do not work.

Comment: Can you run the manufacturer's Hardware Diagnostic App?   That may help you here.

Comment: I cannot run anything as non of the usb ports are working at all.

Comment: Can you download the diagnostic App onto your computer and run it?  You do not need USB ports to do this.

Comment: I can try that, I also just tried booting it and the keyborded flashed very briefly on boot.

Comment: If you have another computer you can use RDP on it to access the computer with USB problems.

Comment: "I have a new pc." Take it back for replacement, unless a tech at the store can point out an obvious issue.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

Suggestion

- Try putting the old disk back.  If that does not work, then its possible that either not all cables are plugged in or part of the power supply may be damaged.
- Its possible that the keyboard works while in the BIOS/UEFI.  So try getting in to the BIOS and check all options related to devices, mice and usb.
- Its possible that the keyboard still works while booting into Windows, so try getting into safemode.
- Take in back to the store, maybe they can find out whats wrong.